# Is it possible for NSFetchResultsController to perform move and update operation, when we change the section of an item?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uicollectionview

Currently, I have a `UICollectionView` which consists of 2 sections

1. Pinned
2. Normal

They looks as following.

---

### Overview

```
== Pinned ===========
|------|
|NOTE0 |
|------|


== Normal ===========

|------|    |------|
|NOTE1 |    |NOTE2 |
|------|    |------|

|------|
|NOTE3 |
|------|
```

---

### NSManagedObject

This is the `NSManagedObject`

```
extension NSPlainNote {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<NSPlainNote> {
        return NSFetchRequest<NSPlainNote>(entityName: "NSPlainNote")
    }

    @NSManaged public var title: String?
    @NSManaged public var body: String?
    @NSManaged public var pinned: Bool
    @NSManaged public var uuid: UUID

}
```

---

### NSFetchResultsController

We use the `Bool` field, to decide whether an item should belong to **Pinned** section, or **Normal** section

This is how our `NSFetchResultsController` looks like

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSPlainNote> = {
    
    // Create a fetch request for the Quake entity sorted by time.
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSPlainNote>(entityName: "NSPlainNote")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [
        NSSortDescriptor(key: "pinned", ascending: false)
    ]
    
    // Create a fetched results controller and set its fetch request, context, and delegate.
    let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
                                                managedObjectContext: CoreDataStack.INSTANCE.persistentContainer.viewContext,
                                                sectionNameKeyPath: "pinned",
                                                cacheName: nil
    )
    controller.delegate = fetchedResultsControllerDelegate
    
    // Perform the fetch.
    do {
        try controller.performFetch()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(error)")
    }
    
    return controller
}()
```

---

### Move and update operation

We then perform the following operations

- Either move the item from Normal section to Pinned section, or move the item from Pinned section to Normal section.
- Update the content.

---

```
func updatePinned(_ objectID: NSManagedObjectID, _ pinned: Bool) {
    let coreDataStack = CoreDataStack.INSTANCE
    let backgroundContext = coreDataStack.backgroundContext

    // TODO: Can we optimize the code, to avoid fetching the entire model object?
    backgroundContext.perform {
        let nsPlainNote = try! backgroundContext.existingObject(with: objectID) as! NSPlainNote
        // This will trigger "move". The cell shall move to different section.
        nsPlainNote.pinned = pinned
        
        // Can we trigger "update" as well?
        if nsPlainNote.pinned {
            nsPlainNote.body = nsPlainNote.title! + "(Pinned)"
        } else {
            nsPlainNote.body = nsPlainNote.title
        }
        
        RepositoryUtils.saveContextIfPossible(backgroundContext)
    }
}
```

---

### NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

```
extension ViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        
        if type == NSFetchedResultsChangeType.insert {
            print("Insert Object: \(newIndexPath)")
            
            blockOperations.append(
                BlockOperation(block: { [weak self] in
                    if let this = self {
                        this.collectionView!.insertItems(at: [newIndexPath!])
                    }
                })
            )
        }
        else if type == NSFetchedResultsChangeType.update {
            print("Update Object: \(indexPath)")
            blockOperations.append(
                BlockOperation(block: { [weak self] in
                    if let this = self {
                        this.collectionView!.reloadItems(at: [indexPath!])
                    }
                })
            )
        }
        else if type == NSFetchedResultsChangeType.move {
            print("Move Object: \(indexPath) to \(newIndexPath)")
            
            blockOperations.append(
                BlockOperation(block: { [weak self] in
                    if let this = self {
                        this.collectionView!.moveItem(at: indexPath!, to: newIndexPath!)
                    }
                })
            )
        }
        else if type == NSFetchedResultsChangeType.delete {
            print("Delete Object: \(indexPath)")
            
            blockOperations.append(
                BlockOperation(block: { [weak self] in
                    if let this = self {
                        this.collectionView!.deleteItems(at: [indexPath!])
                    }
                })
            )
        }
    }
    
    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
        if type == NSFetchedResultsChangeType.insert {
            print("Insert Section: \(sectionIndex)")
            
            blockOperations.append(
                BlockOperation(block: { [weak self] in
                    if let this = self {
                        this.collectionView!.insertSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex))
                    }
                })
            )
        }
        else if type == NSFetchedResultsChangeType.update {
            print("Update Section: \(sectionIndex)")
            
            blockOperations.append(
                BlockOperation(block: { [weak self] in
                    if let this = self {
                        this.collectionView!.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex))
                    }
                })
            )
        }
        else if type == NSFetchedResultsChangeType.delete {
            print("Delete Section: \(sectionIndex)")
            
            blockOperations.append(
                BlockOperation(block: { [weak self] in
                    if let this = self {
                        this.collectionView!.deleteSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex))
                    }
                })
            )
        }
    }
    
    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        collectionView!.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in
            for operation: BlockOperation in self.blockOperations {
                operation.start()
            }
        }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
            self.blockOperations.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        })
    }
}
```

---

We want to move and update an item from **Normal** section to **Pinned** section.

We execute

```
updatePinned(objectId, true)
```

Only the following is printed

```
Move Object: Optional([1, 12]) to Optional([0, 0])
```

We expect besides `NSFetchedResultsChangeType.move`, `NSFetchedResultsChangeType.update` should happen too. But, it doesn't. Only `NSFetchedResultsChangeType.move` is happen.

---

### Workaround (This is a wrong approach! Do NOT apply this!)

I try to `reloadData` after the end of animation.

```
func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    collectionView!.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in
        for operation: BlockOperation in self.blockOperations {
            operation.start()
        }
    }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
        self.blockOperations.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        
        // Do not do this! As, it will cause NSFetchedResultsController malfuntion after some time. 
        // You will soon realize NSFetchedResultsController is wrongly placing a pinned 
        // note in normal section.
        // Or even worst, it will issue didChange callback with wrong NSFetchedResultsChangeType value
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

It looks like thing works fine at first sight. However, if you perform pin and unpin operation for several times, you will notice that `NSFetchedResultsController` is placing note in wrong section. It will place the pinned note in normal section, and a normal note in pinned section.

Or even worst, it will issue `didChange` callback with wrong `NSFetchedResultsChangeType` value

---

### Demo

The following is the demo code to illustrate the mentioned problem.

https://github.com/yccheok/UICollectionView-02/tree/stackoverflow

[image]

As you can see, after move, update is not performed. We can observe

1. Blue pin icon is not drawn
2. Orange background color body text is not update

The update will only be performed, if we perform scrolling explicitly.

---

May I know, what is the correct way for me to change an item's section (So that there is move animation), and update item's content (So that `cellForItemAt` function will be called)?

Answer (score 2):

(Crossporting my answer over at r/iOSProgramming so Stackoverflow users find it too)
NSFRC moves always imply an update. The only reason an object would “move” is if its value for the sort key changes, which means that object has been updated as well.

Edit:
I see, I think you've hit one of the common edge cases in UICollectionView reloading in tandem with NSFRCs. You shouldn't use `reloadItems()` here, regardless of how unintuitive that is. Instead, use `cellForRow(at:)` and create a method that updates the data for that cell. This is true for both UICollectionView and UITableView.

Check how everybody else does it:

- [JSQDataSourcesKit](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQDataSourcesKit/blob/develop/Source/FetchedResultsDelegate.swift#L125)
- [CoreStore](https://github.com/JohnEstropia/CoreStore/blob/develop/Demo/%E2%AD%90%EF%B8%8FSources/%E2%AD%90%EF%B8%8FDemos/%E2%AD%90%EF%B8%8FClassic/%E2%AD%90%EF%B8%8FColorsDemo/%E2%AD%90%EF%B8%8FClassic.ColorsDemo.ListViewController.swift#L75)

Comment: Even so, collectionView's cellForItemAt will not be called if we issue `this.collectionView!.moveItem(at: indexPath!, to: newIndexPath!)` after receiving "move" from FRC. As collectionView's cellForItemAt is the only place to redraw cell UI. So, what is a good way to have collectionView's cellForItemAt being called, when there is a "move" from FRC?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the links. After going the code, I have 2 questions in mind. May I know, is there any source which talks about `this.collectionView!.reloadItems(at: [indexPath!])` shouldn't be used, when receiving `NSFetchedResultsChangeType.update`?

Comment: Another question is, when handling `NSFetchedResultsChangeType.update`, I notice they handle by `collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [old])` followed by `collectionView?.insertItems(at: [new])`. But, if we perform so, we are not able to observe any animation of moving an item from one location to another location.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng  I don't remember seeing any Apple documentation on avoiding `reloadItems` with NSFRCs. This is knowledge passed on by people who already experimented on it and uses NSFRCs a lot (including the use of delete+insert in place of moves). If anybody says this is documented, please ask for a link and do post it in your original post.